# Tableau running average

Tags: average

I have a column of numeric data and another column by date.  I'm trying to calculate a running average by week.  I'm using a table calculation, Running Total on Average.  This is not producing the running average I am expecting.

Example:

For 3rd week Running average, the running average is calculating the first week average + second week average + third week average, and then taking the average of those 3 numbers.  What I want it to do is take all prior 3 week data and THEN take one single average as a whole.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to have done it.  Calculated field:

RUNNING_SUM(SUM([NPS]))/RUNNING_SUM(COUNT([NPS]))